# Local domain and "where are you in the network" checker

Tags: php, html, dns, qr-code, local

How to check if user is visiting site from our own local network or common internet.

Suppose, If somebody scans the qr code in our restaurant, it links to something, which is checking, are you connected to the local network or you're opening it from global? (no idea how)

Local - redirecting to the local domain (no idea how i can do this also, eg. restaurant.menu)

Global - redirecting to the global domain (eg. menu.com)

Comment: When you say local network does it mean connect to the router in the restaurant via wifi or lan?

Comment: @endeavour, yes. it checks are you connected to the wifi or not. if yes - it redirects you to example.somehtinglocal or if not - to example.com.

Comment: Then this is not possible with pure php. This is a networking question. The actual solution can only be figured out once the architecture is understood. Is your website hosted locally (and the same server serves external requests too)? What kind of router you have? Also, if you host your website on a local server then I assume you have a static IP, do you? I am wondering though why do you want such a setup, what is the objective? I am sure there would be a better implementation

Answer (score 1):

You can check the IP of the customer and compare it with IP range of your network. If the customer IP falls in your range redirect the user to local site otherwise to your global site.

You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` to get IP of user visiting the site from the QR code.

Comment: i'm zero in this.. is it in .htaccess?

Comment: No you need to create a PHP file and then that PHP file and open that file url whenever qr is scanned, which will check the IP address of user visiting.

Comment: thanks. do you have any ideas how the php code will look like? my ip's are from 10.100.109.10 to 10.100.109.256

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a dns record for your local IP (external IP). The IPs mentioned in the comment `10.100.109.10-256` are private IPs and not publicly accessible. These wont work, search on google with what is my ip and I am sure you will get many options.

Once done you can create a script which will get user ip address (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`) and do a [`gethostbyaddr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) lookup to get the hostname associated with that IP. If the hostname matches the one you have set, your visitor is from a local connection.

For the redirection to work, if your website is hosted on server that is not in the same network as your router then you need to have a public facing domain name (ie. restaurant.menu should be reachable publicly)

A second approach could be to redirect the traffic at the router level. If your router allows you can setup a redirection in the router itself. If it does not you will need to setup a dns server. In this dns server you will specify the desired (local) IP address for the domain. You router needs to have a backup dns to keep resolving other domains.

These are hacks but if implemented correctly they will provide very predictable results.